# Nilpotent Quotients Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'd appreciate if anyone could point out any wrongdoing in my proof, since something seems a little bit off.

Suppose $G / Z(G)$ is nilpotent.

Then there exists an upper central series $Z(G) / Z(G) \unlhd H_1 /Z(G) \unlhd \dots \unlhd H_{k}/Z(G) = G / Z(G)$ for $G / Z(G)$.

Given that $H_{i+1}/Z(G)$ is by definition the preimage in $G/Z(G)$ under the natural projection homomorphism of $Z(G / Z(G) / H_{i} /Z(G)) = Z(G/H_{i})$ (cancellation of quotients done using third isomorphism theorem), then by the lattice isomorphism theorem, $H_{i+1}$ is the preimage of $Z(G/H_{i})$ in $G$ under its natural projection homomorphism.

Thus, ${1} \unlhd H_{1} \unlhd \dots \unlhd H_{k} = G$ is an upper central series for $G$, so that $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: All is right...

Comment: Thanks for the verification. My main concern was that both $H_{i+1}$ (in $G$) and $H_{i+1}/Z(G)$ (in $G / Z(G)$) are both preimages of $Z(G / H_{i})$. It seemed ... not right.

Comment: If $A(=Z(G))<B(=H_i)<C(=H_{i+1})<G$ then anyway $C$ and $C/A$ are both preimages of the same subgroup of $G/B$.

Comment: I you would like a quibble, then you should say "the upper central series" rather than "an upper central series", because the upper central series is unique.